# Do you want questions like these?

Tags: discussion

In sensus plenior, the metaphoric meaning is not free-for-all allegory, but is based on a set of rules which demand consistency of meaning throughout the scriptures.

As such, if leaven represents sin, it must represent sin everywhere it occurs. A challenge to the proposed metaphor would include a reference to the Kingdom of Heaven being like leaven.

The burden falls to the one defending the proposal to show a legitimate interpretation where the kingdom of Heaven is like sin.

An alternate proposal is made saying that it represents teaching, and that meaning holds until all portions linked by remez have been evaluated and agree,

On one hand, this is a perfect venue for such discussions, however, I would expect to have close to 1000 such discussions concerning metaphopric meaning on words alone.

They would look like: In sensus plenior, what is the metaphoric meaning of **_**.

Another type of question would concern word play.  Unlike metaphor, word play is based on the meaning of the word and it's puns. These are not required to be applied uniformly, only that they actually mean what they are permitted to mean. These are the source of double entendre.

"took' also mens 'married' must/can it mean so in Verse **_**?

These questions are particular to sensus plenior. Do they belong in BH? These types of questions would form the dictionary of sensus plenior metaphor.

Comment: I certainly don't want to see thousands (or even dozens) of these sorts of questions at this stage.  You've got a blog for that.  I'm concerned already that you are treating this site as a blog and it isn't that.  (Or at least the blog aspect is at most a quarter of what we are all about.)

Comment: Yet you are asking for references. I asked you before if you want me to reference a site I create. That answer, since it was ignored is presumably, No. Now you don't want it here either. I will do it either way the community wishes.

Comment: I don't always see your comments and I don't always answer them.  (One hint, if you want someone specific to see a comment is to use the `@name` thingy.  The rules about when people get notified are a bit complicated and I don't know them fully.  But that usually works if they've already been part of a post.)  I've answered my own question on referencing your own work.  I think it's probably the best thing for you to do at this point.  One or two of these questions is fine.  1000 is not.  Maybe after the community has formed and the site is out of beta, we can look into this again.

Comment: I see.  I have an allotment of questions. Good luck with your community.

Comment: Everyone can ask as many questions as they want, _but_ you asked if we wanted the sort of questions you are proposing and I told you that I didn't want to see tons at this point.  I know I've been hard on you (probably unfairly), but I hope that we can work through it.  If you were to ask a handful of these sorts of questions, we could see how they go.  I certainly think they would be interesting if you follow Caleb's advice.

Answer (score 3):

I think these kind of questions are on topic here and more than welcome, however I think you are wrong about them being peculiar to 'Sensus Plenior'.

In fact, having watched your usage vs other people's interpretation methods, I think your usage of that term is different than what most hermeneutical experts use and -- while the concept you have in your head might be quite valid -- it isn't valid to label as many things as you do with it. For example "leaven" isn't an example of Sensus Plenior so much as it is just an metaphor/allegory to start with. Sensus Plenor is more applicable when you have, say, an OT prophet speaking about something very concrete that might have had literal application for their immediate audience, but also has figurative application to later events that they were unaware of.

That being said, the kind of questions you propose are probably quite welcome but you will confuse people more than necessary by trying to pigeon hole them to that label. They are questions that will need to be answered by anybody dealing with those texts even if they reject the formal/official concept of Sensus Plenior.

Comment: Good insight.  I'm not even sure we should encourage asking questions that are looking for really specific interpretations.  I feel more comfortable with questions that invite a broad range of approaches.

Comment: The differentiation is important because popular typology employing metaphor says leaven is sin. There are no rules to intelligently discuss that. In sensus plenior you have a framework for discussion.  Can you explain that what I do isn't sensus plenior?

Comment: When someone says that leaven is sin, they should be able to identify that it is free-for-all allegory with some weight of tradition. If he says it is teaching, he should identify that it should mean teaching everywhere it exists in the scriptures following the rules of sensus plenior. When you use sin as the meaning only a few places will turn up pictures of Christ. When you use teaching, every place that it is used turns up a picture of Christ. The hidden meaning is always a picture of Christ, and the hidden meaning is defined as sensus plenior.

Comment: If the question is asked, :"What does ___ mean" you generally get different answers that get voted on. If that is the form you wish, then the answer could say "In popular free-for-all allegory it means this (ref) and this (ref) and this (ref). In sensus plenior it means this: (123 verses validating the meaning). This invites a broad range of approaches.